# Jest manual mock sub modules with top level export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

when using React and Jest I encountered a use case for manual mocks, that I do not know how to overcome. Given the following structure:

```
.
├── code.test.tsx
└── module
    ├── __mocks__
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── module.tsx
    └── submodule
        ├── __mocks__
        └── index.tsx
```

I am writing tests inside `code.test.tsx`. The components `module` and `submodule` do contain manual file mocks that returns dummy code for unit testing purposes.

`module/index.tsx` acts as an export point for the component itself and submodule:

```
export * from './submodule'
export { module } from './module.tsx'
```

This way the imports inside `code.tsx` are more organized:

```
import { module, submodule } from './module'
```

Finally inside `code.test.tsx` I mock the import of `module` by calling `jest.mock('./module')`. The desired behavior should be that `module` and `submodule` are getting mocked since both components contain a `__mocks__` folder.

Since `module/__mocks__` exports a mock that only defines itself, the underlying components are undefined. In this case I would normally adjust the imports to point to the components directly. But since the imports provide advanced readability I want to recursively mock the subfolders where ever there is a `__mocks__` directory. Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Jest docs on using manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules), it is explicitly required that you mock the module present in the `__mocks__` directory.

> When we require that module in our tests, explicitly calling
> jest.mock('./moduleName') is required.

Please ensure you have explicitly mocked the module and submodule imports in your test file.